# How to count sub-categories in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have a Model called Topic and Problem:

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 250, unique = True)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length = 250, unique = True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'Topic'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Topics'

    def get_url(self):
        return reverse('problemdirectory', args = [self.slug])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Problem(models.Model):
    slug = models.CharField(max_length = 250, unique = True)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

    questionToProblem = models.TextField()
    solutionToProblem = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('questionToProblem',)

    def get_url(self):
        return reverse('solution_details', args = [self.topic.slug, self.slug])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.questionToProblem
```

Topic is like a "folder", or category to Problem.  How would I count the number of problems a certain Topic has in views.py and reference it in the HTML template?:

```
def topicList(request):
    topics = Topic.objects.all()
    #numberOfProblems = Problem.objects.count()
    Problem.objects.filter(topic__name= topic).count()
    topics.order_by('name')

    return render(request, 'topiclist.html', {'topics': topics})
```

I have tried importing Q and filter() with no success so far.

Comment: what do you mean by sub-category? There you don't have any sub-category

Comment: Problem is a sub-category of Topic.  I want to count the number of problems in a Topic in views.  Is this explanation clearer?

Comment: just use django ORM by using annotation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about calculated field in `Topic` class?

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 250, unique = True)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length = 250, unique = True)

    @property
    def problem_count(self):
        return Problem.objects.filter(topic = self).count()
```

Then it will be available in your `topics` variable

```
def topicList(request):
    topics = Topic.objects.all().order_by('name')    
    return render(request, 'topiclist.html', {'topics': topics})
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Can't believe I couldn't think of that. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Add a `related_name` as follows.

```
class Problem(models.Model):
   slug = models.CharField(max_length = 250, unique = True)
   topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, related_name="problems", on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

And add a property method in `Topic` model like this-

```
class Topic(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length = 250, unique = True)
   slug = models.CharField(max_length = 250, unique = True)

   @property
   def total_problems(self):
       return self.problems.all().count()
```

You can now get the total number of problems with every topic as follows.

```
topics = Topic.objects.all()
for topic in topics:
    total_problems = topic.total_problems
```

You can show the problem count in your templates inside a for loop as following.

```
{{topic.total_problems}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.db.models import Count
def topicList(request):
    topics = Topic.objects.all().annotation(problem_count=Count('topic_set'))
    #numberOfProblems = Problem.objects.count()
    Problem.objects.filter(topic__name= topic).count()
    topics.order_by('name')

    return render(request, 'topiclist.html', {'topics': topics})
```